# Accelerators Not Working JavaFX with SceneBuilder 2.0

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

**The Goal:**

The goal is simple, I'm simply looking to implement an Accelerator for my MenuBar File Item "Clear all markers". I'm currently working on a mapping application and I want the option to clear all the waypoints. I'm using ArcGIS MAPS by ESRI to insert the MAP.

**Current Behavior:**

Works if I click the Edit menu and then click on the clear all. But doesn't work for my accelerator (Ctrl+Shift+E).

**Code:**

***FXML File:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" stylesheets="@DarkTheme.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="company.navigationapp.view.RootLayoutController">
<top>
  <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleExit" text="Exit" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClearAll" onMenuValidation="#handleClearAll" text="Clear All Markers">
                 <accelerator>
                    <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="E" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="DOWN" shortcut="UP" />
                 </accelerator></MenuItem>
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
        <items>
          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAbout" text="About" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
</top>
</BorderPane>
```

***Relevant Section of the RootLayoutController.java Class:***

```
public void handleClearAll() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Confirm Clear All");
    alert.setHeaderText("You sure you want to clear all markers?");
    alert.showAndWait();
    if(alert.getResult() == ButtonType.OK) {
         mainApp.ClearAllMarkers();
    }
    else{
        alert.close();
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

If everything is set up this way, the accelerators work, but taking my BorderPane RootLayout and executing the following command:

```
rootLayout.setCenter(mapView);
```

Causes the accelerator to stop working.

The root layout is initialized as such:

```
// Load root layout from fxml file.
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

// Show the scene containing the root layout.
Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);

// Give the controller access to the main app.
RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setMainApp(this);

primaryStage.show();
```

The mapView is then created by the following code:

```
final ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.createTopographic());

MgrsGrid MGRSGrid = new MgrsGrid();

mapView = new MapView();
mapView.setMap(map);

mapView.setGrid(MGRSGrid);
```

So simply without the:

```
rootLayout.setCenter(mapView);
```

My accelerator works, but when I add that it stops working. Any ideas as to why this may be the case?

**SceneBuilder Screenshot:**

Please see this photo below for how it's set up with SceneBuilder, the code should explain the rest.
[Image Showing SceneBuilder Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTWby.png)

**EDIT:**

*Probably a solution/reason why this doesn't work:*

So as it turns out the ArcGIS SDK that I'm using has its own built in Accelerators:

[ArcGIS Accelerator Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/framework/Accelerator.html)

That likely clashes with the accelerators I'm trying to use, so perhaps the solution is either to figure out the built in accelerators that the SDK contains and then which ones I can use for my own benefit, or figuring out a way to disable their accelerators altogether so that I can simply use my own.

I'll update on the progress.

Comment: worksforme - so the problem is probably in the code you are _not_ showing ;) Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: Yeah thank you, actually what caused it was a problem with the actual MapOverlay. I've edited my problem to reflect this.